# Ajax loading animation like this

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, loader

I have seached high and low for an animation exactly like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/pedox/yed68/embedded/result/

Problem is that its made is css and while most browser don't support that yet, its not really an option.

http://loadinfo.net/ <- Too small and simple.

http://preloaders.net/en/horizontal <- They have some horizontal bars, but the animation speed a linear.

http://www.netwaver.com/21/8-ajax-loading-icon-generators/ <- Here is a list. The two above are mentioned plus a few additional ones.

There are more sites out there but I lost some of the links. But the thing that they have in common is that they are to small and don't look like the above.

I think I have seen this animation in "Modern UI/Metro UI" or what ever its called now in Windows 8.

Hope there are some people with better search or graphic skills that can find a nice simple load with animated circles in varying speed.

Comment: 37 FR (the second in this list) at http://preloaders.net/en/horizontal is pretty close...

Comment: Maybe i'm just being to picky about the loader animation. That one just looks odd in some way I can't really explain, since I'm no UI expert.

Comment: Most _modern_ browsers do support CSS3. But if you have very specific needs you can always write your own using the jQuery UI transitions.

Comment: I guess I could depend on CSS3 ... my users are seem to have the newest version of the browsers. Mostly Firefox and Chorme ... I guess I could extend the example I found and posted in this thread. Just hoped that I did not have to do it my self and hoped there were something out there already.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the CSS3 only solution is not work with IE<=9. I tried with my web app for mobile as well and CSS3 solution works for Android 4 default browser.

Comment: The users on my site mostyl uses the newest browsers and users that don't I really don't care about :-)